# How can I create a task in Gradle that depends on all files in a directory?

Tags: gradle

I have a directory, let's call it `inputs`. I need to create a task that will:

1. read in all of the files in the `inputs` directory, ie: `inputs/*`.
2. produce a new file somewhere else that combines these files in some way. (For the sake of example, you can assume I just want to concatenate all of the files into a single output file.)

How do I set up the task correctly such that the following requirements are met?

- requesting the task a second time when nothing has changed doesn't execute the task ("Already up to date").
- adding, editing, or **deleting** files in the `inputs` directory causes the task to be "out of date", and so requesting it after any of those has happened will cause it to re-execute.

Comment: `inputs.dir("thedir")`. https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html#dir-java.lang.Object-. Or `@InputDirectory`if you're creating a task class: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/InputDirectory.html

Comment: @JBNizet Sounds like the answer! Thanks. If I had to combine files from two directories would I just invoke `inputs.dir` twice, once for each?

Comment: Yes. The inputs are cumulative.

Comment: @JBNizet why not post this as an answer?